# how to display a fetch of react-redux on the Drawer.Screen header

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I would like to display data on a Status header bar of Drawer Screen.

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {get_agency_direction} from '../store/Log/Dir/DirActions';
import Direction from '../screens/Direction/Direction';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const RDirection = () => {`enter code here`
  const info_agency = useSelector(state => state.DirReducers.info_agency);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(async value => {
        dispatch(get_agency_direction(value));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

  console.log(info_agency);

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Direction"
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 40,
        },
      }}
      drawerType="permanent"
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerDirection {...props} />}
      backBehavior="history">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Direction"
        component={Direction}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          header: () => (
            <HeaderUser
              Gtitle='Noblesse voyages'
              Depart="Douala"
              Arrive="Yaoundé"
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.toggleDrawer();
              }}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            height: 70,
          },
        })}
      />

    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default RDirection;
```

The return code by console.log(info_agency) :

```
[{
  "id":46,
  "NomCh":"Bricks",
  "PrenomCh":"Wandem foué",
  "MotdepasseCh":"$2b$10$/4ugSQMptSp6VqScLcHl4.V9oyrgnAk7NNmtZIeRZ7usT1hcMsbB2",
  "NumeroCh":673845359,
  "NomAgence":"Talla voyages",
  "NomOrganisation":"Talla",
  "idch":49,
  "CodesecureAgence":"$2b$10$lJ0oBoWr7vnI0Ix.YpWDo.tsiYJ8bSm/yLhVSDf8kgT4CfYFZm7Bm",
  "NumeroSerieAg":"",
}]
```

I would have a truck like that

```
    header: () => (
     <HeaderUser
       Gtitle={info_agency.NomAgence}
       Depart={/* Not important*/}
       Arrive={/* Not important*/}
       onPress={() => {
        navigation.toggleDrawer();
       }}
     />
```

I tried with a Flatlist, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Your console.log shows that you're response returns an array. You're trying to call info_agency.NomAgence which won't work since it's not an object.

If you want to pass the title into Gtitle you would need to get the object form the array:

```js
info_agency[0].NomAgence
```